# Hosting react and nodejs heroku but frontend not work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I try hosting my website in `Heroku` use react and `nodejs`.
I'm successfully hosting my app but, why only the server running but the client not?

This is the result
[image]

This is my folder
[image]

Comment: How does the Procfile look like?

Comment: Which port does the server listen to?

Comment: @Jkarttunen web: node server.js

Comment: @Jkarttunen 5000

Comment: What's te server.js like?

Comment: What do the heroku logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Port needs to be dynamic from the env variable

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```